# Hom and Tensor Product of Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading Claudio Procesi's book on Lie groups and on page 105 there is something I don't understand.

Let $U,V,W$ be vector spaces. Let us consider the product space $\hom(V,W) \times \hom(U,V) $ together with the map

$$f : \hom(V,W) \times \hom(U,V) \rightarrow \hom(U,W)$$

that sends a pair $(v, \varphi)$ to $v \circ \varphi$. Suppose I have an elementary tensor $v \otimes \varphi$  in $ \hom(V,W) \otimes\hom(U,V) $. By the universal property of tensor products there is a unique linear map

$$ L : \hom(V,W) \otimes \hom(U,V) \rightarrow \hom(U,W)$$

such that on elementary tensors, $L(v\otimes \varphi) = v \circ \varphi$.

Now 1.5.1 of pg 105 claims that for any $u \in U$, we have that

$$(v \otimes \varphi)(u) = v \langle \varphi | u\rangle$$

where $\langle \varphi | u\rangle$ is defined on page 16 to be the value of the linear form $\varphi$ on $u$. I am confused as to  how they obtained that equality above - is it ***really an equality***? I don't see it directly but I think it comes from the fact that

$$\hom(U,V) \cong V \otimes U^\ast.$$

Comment: I agree with Brad - on the left hand side of your penultimate equation, you have $v \otimes \phi$, an element of the tensor product of two hom spaces.  It doesn't make sense to "evaluate" this at $u \in U$, so you should imagine a silent $L$ or regard the whole equation as a definition.

Comment: @mt_ What if we now take $U = W = V$, would this make sense?

Comment: no matter what U,W,V are, literally speaking $v\otimes \phi$ isn't a function that can be applied to objects of type $u \in U$.  The only natural way I can see to make sense of it is to regard the equation as a definition.

Comment: @mt_ Thanks, I agree that the equality does not make sense. That's why I was confused in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, it wants to simply mean 
$$\left[L(v \otimes \varphi)\right](u) = v(\varphi ( u))$$
 well.. this notation $\langle\varphi|u\rangle$ now confused me too, as $\varphi$ is not a *linear form*. The $L$ should be understood, because without it the LHS gives syntax error, as  mt_ wrote in the comment..